# Ubuntu 18.04 overheating after ffmpeg installation

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, video, ffmpeg, overheating

I have recently installed **ffmpeg** by:

```bsh
sudo snap install ffmpeg
```

on my **Ubuntu 18.04** desktop.

Unfortunately, when I play a video (same problem with **mp4, mkv, 3gp**) , the temperature starts to rise over 80 Celsius degrees (usually it ranges between 50 and 68). I have tried to play a video with preinstalled video player and with VLC. On the other hand, videos played from firefox do not seem to be affected by the problem.

I have removed ffmpeg by:

```bsh
sudo snap remove ffmpeg
```

then its dependencies:

```bsh
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libavutil-dev
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libavutil55
```

I have restarted the system, but the problem is still here. Playing a video, the temperature goes over 80 degrees, the video itself seems to be displayed somehow slowed down, fragmented.

I already know that my **NVIDIA geforce 845M** has problems with mesa and updated video packages (in fact, I am terrified of upgrading the system to Ubuntu 20).

Does anybody know how to come back to the system before ffmpeg installation?

---

**Additional information:**

```bsh
lspci | grep VGA
```

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core
> Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

```bsh
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

> OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.2.8

Comment: Which player do you use for playing video?VLC?or your browsee?Have your tried different videos with different codecs?Intel 4th gen does not support x265 or vp9 codecs so it switches to software decoding maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I got the problem with both preinstalled video player and vlc. On the other hand, videos played from firefox do not seem to be affected by the problem.

Comment: Moreover, I have tried videos in mp4, mkv, 3gp. Same problem.

Comment: Try running vainfo to see if drivers are affected.And does cpu usage increase upon playing a video?